# why pointer having 12 difference to next memory location

Tags: c, pointers

why below program taking memory difference to next location fix 12 in next memory location or its have some logic  for char/float /int have diffrencet different -2 difference to next location

include
    #include

```
int main () {

   char  var;
   char  *ptr;
   char  **pptr;
    char  ***ppptr;
   char  ****pppptr;

   var = 'M';

   /* take the address of var */
   ptr = &var;

   /* take the address of ptr using address of operator & */
   pptr = &ptr;

   ppptr=&pptr;

   ppptr=&pptr;
   ppptr=&pptr;
   pppptr=&ppptr;

   /* take the value using pptr */
   printf("Value of var = %d\n", var );
   printf("Value available at *ptr = %c....and address is %u\n", *ptr ,ptr);
   printf("Value available at **pptr = %c....and address is %u\n", **pptr,pptr);
   printf("Value available at ***ppptr = %c....and address is %u\n", ***ppptr ,ppptr);
   printf("Value available at ****pppptr = %c....and address is %u\n", ****pppptr,pppptr);
   getch();
   return 0;
}
//out put
///-----------------------------------------------
Value of var = 77;
Value available at *ptr = M....and address is 11401207
Value available at **pptr = M....and address is 11401192   why differnceis 12 in memory locaton 
Value available at ***ppptr = M....and address is 11401180
Value available at ****pppptr = M....and address is 11401168
```

Comment: First, to print out pointers you must use %p which is meant for it. As for why? Because the compiler decided to do so.

Comment: It seems a little bit unusual. You'd better ask your compiler vendor why it is leaving gaps between variables on the stack.

Comment: compiler does not assume any particular order of allocation variable on stack, so you cannot expect any relation between addresses of sequential variables.

Comment: What "next memory location"? That's not what is happening there. Your question is alike to asking "why these 2 red cars have a blue car parked between them"?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala But in this case, it looks like there is empty space between them, assuming pointers are 4 or 8 bytes long (12 bytes would be an unusual size for a pointer.) It would be interesting to see the assembly output if OP is up for it.

Comment: @Veer Rathore It will be informative to include `printf("void * size: %zu\n", sizeof(void*));` to know your code's `void*` size.  What is that result?

Comment: @ Ian Abbott  yes Dude that's i am asking for ...........why 12 only and its constant also to next location

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking about why the address of `ptr`, as judged by printing the value of `pptr` using `scanf` field descriptor `%u`, appears to differ from the address of the next-declared local variable, `pptr`, by 12 bytes.  And so on down the line for the other local variables, I presume.

In fact, as @SouravGhosh already described in his answer, the `%u` field descriptor does not correspond properly to pointer arguments, and therefore the effects of your `scanf` calls, including all aspects of the output, are undefined.

**However**, the actual results don't really matter for the purposes of the question.  The C language provides no justification for assuming any particular ordering or difference between the addresses of any function's local variables.  It is at the discretion of the compiler.  There is therefore no general answer to the question.

If we *hypothesize* that the output you observed happens to accurately reflect the differences between the addresses of the local variables -- which is by no means certain -- then that would suggest that the compiler is intentionally leaving padding between the variables.  It is entirely free to do so, for any purpose whatever.  For example, the compiler might be trying to minimize the potential impact of off-by-one errors in code that accesses the local variables via the pointers to them.

Answer (score 1):

First, a proper way to print pointers is with `%p` and with the pointer converted to `void *` when passed to `printf`, as in `printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr);`. Since you mention in a comment having used `%P`, differing from the `%u` shown in the question, I will presume that incorrect case is a typo, and you have reproduced the problem using `%p` with results similar to those shown in the question.

In that case, what is likely happening is that the compiler is storing the pointers `ptr`, `pptr`, `ppptr`, and `pppptr` at addresses that happen to be 12 bytes apart. Of course, it could store them merely four or eight bytes apart if pointers in your C implementation happened to be four or eight bytes in size. However, the compiler may be storing other things between the pointers, perhaps addresses of the strings you use in the `printf` statements or other incidental values. This makes me suspect that you compiled without optimization enabled. If you recompile with optimization, you will likely see different results.

In any case, a better explanation of the results would likely be had by asking the compiler to show the assembly code it generates (as by using the `-S` switch with GCC).

Answer (score -1):

Using `%u` for printing pointer address results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Use `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void *`.

Comment: Not really an answer to the actual question, more of a comment

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Really? Why? How do you possibly justify the output of a program containing undefined behavior?

Comment: Because the question isn’t about this. Even if it is undefined behavior in this case “it works” and the question is about completely different thing.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That is the most dangerous thing about UB..."It works!!", or at least, it appears to be.

Comment: And when they edit the question to use %p and the result is still the same and the question remains, this will still not answer the actual question.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen well, you're correct, but I cannot try to answer a question which is not there in the first place. If the question is edited, the answer also needs to be.

Comment: No....My question is every memory address taking difference of  12 for next pointer location in case of my program if if will print using %P or %d % U all will give me memory location only..... Hope it will help u to understand my question

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The question does not contain undefined behavior. The question contains behavior not defined **by the C standard**. There are several other factors at play that do inform us about the behavior. The universe does not go haywire simply because somebody did not follow the C standard. Processors still move electricity around the way they were designed, and operating systems still function. And, in this case, the compiler falls back to behavior recognizable from experience. It is printing addresses where pointers are, which are not stored contiguously from each other.